# SDL ignores std::cin

Tags: c++, visual-studio, user-interface, sdl, sdl-2

I started learing SDL using visual studio 2015, and I am following a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7hF5BiPhP8Q).
I already have everything setup.

This tutorial is all about drawing a blank window. After drawing the window the author adds a `std::cin` to take in an integer so that the window does not quit immediately.

The problem is that I have done the same exact thing but my window quits instantly.

This is my `main.cpp`:

```
#include"SDL.h"
#include<iostream>
#include"MainGame.h"

int main(int argc, char *args[]) {
using namespace std;

MainGame maingame;
maingame.run();

cout<<"Enter any key: "
int a;
    cin>>a;


return 0;
}
```

This same thing works in the video. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you try using a debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like visual studio isn't told to pay attention to the console, so it just throws away `std::cin`.

Try replacing it with:

```
SDL_Delay(1000); // do nothing for 1 second
```

Comment: @thebournegenius Accepting the answer (the tick) and upvoting is SOs way of saying "thanks".